# Updates not being checked in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I am updating a textfile in another program and the "this file has been modified by another program notepad++" prompt is not displaying.. If I look in file explorer the files last modified date will be accurate but the changes nor the prompt will be displayed on Notepad++.

I want the old live checking of Notepad++ and the prompt listed above to be in place, is there a setting to turn that on again? I don't know why it got off in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

`Settings` > `Preferences` > `MISC.` > `File Status Auto-Detection`

`Enabled` should be checked, and optionally `Update silently` if you want it to update without the annoying message box.

Comment: By doing this it updates but it does not display the prompt before, even though I have Update silently unchecked. Any ideas?

Comment: Beats me. Maybe check the [Wiki](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Main_Page) or [Forums](http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/).